# Why does my LSTM stablize to fix point?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I have trained a LSTM by a sequence, and try to test if it can synthesize some output sequence, but interestingly and unfortunately, it very quickly, i.e, after 2 time steps, stablizes to a fix output, meaning a sequence of exact same values.

Now I have changed the initialization, but the outputs are always the same after 2 steps. What might be wrong in the training or sampling?

Sorry that I cannot give more context, because the whole program is a big too large to post here.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your training or sampling - this is the expected behavior for a "pure" LSTM network. To model the variance in your data, don't make the network predict the values at the next time step directly. Rather, your network should give you a probability distribution over the possible values for the next time step, from which you can then sample.

Two examples of how you can do this:

- Discrete data, e.g. text: stack a softmax layer on top of the LSTM, which gives you the probabilites for each letter, then sample from these probabilites - this is also implemented in Karparthy's infamous [char-rnn](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn), see the paragraph "Temperature"
- Continuous data, e.g. timeseries: make the network predict the parameters of a mixture distribution (i.e. a linear combination of Gaussians), then sample from this - I very much recommend the section on handwriting prediction in [Graves 2013](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850), or you can have a look at chapter 5 of [this report](https://github.com/jrieke/lstm-biology/blob/master/Project%20Report.pdf) I recently wrote for a research project